# The best method(s) to identify/verify the presence of a small organic molecule

Tags: spectroscopy

What is the fastest or the most definite method (preferentially a single unexpensive method) for verifying the presence of a certain small orgnic molecule which is expected to be of >90% purity in a "powdry" sample (known solvent is also availble)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Proton NMR, if the molecule is 90% or better should be fairly clear assuming it has protons in the structure